# Tagging a Google docs revision

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

Is it possible to "tag" a Google doc revision? Similar to tagging a revision in a source control system.

I'd like to continue working on a document, however I'd like to log which revision of the document I have sent to a client in the past. I'd prefer not to have to save lots of different versions.

So there is a clear distinction between the last revision they had seen and what has changed recently.

---

I've had a search around and can assume it's not a feature, but I wonder if anyone has written a script to do something similar.

Answer (score 5):

Google just added a "named versions" feature to Google Docs. Google Docs always kept copies of previous versions but now you have the ability to name them.

> [...] open a document, spreadsheet, or presentation.
>   At the top, click "File" and then "Version history" and then "See version history".
>   In the right panel, click a timestamp to see an earlier version of a file. You can see the people who edited the file, and the changes they made in the color next to their name.
>   **Optional: To name a version, click "More actions" and then "Name this version".**
>   To see edits in more detail, go to the right panel, choose a version, and click the Arrow Right arrow.

Source: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843

[image: Screenshot of Google Docs version history named versions]

Answer (score 3):

There is currently no way to tag or add notes to an item in the revision history.

The most common workaround is to **Make A Copy** of key versions, and name/organize them appropriately.

While the "revision history" feature has some similar functionality to that of a source control system, it really isn't one. Personally, I would save the file out into a local folder which is set up as a repo and use an actual source control system for this.

Comment: while i (kinda) like your answer, it's totally does not conform to the [DRY principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

Answer (score -1):

An older question, so you might have an answer now.. however there is an addin I am using:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/collavate/bdgngcpdlbijgaenlomgkfppplgmdfpn?utm_source=permalink

it does a bit more.. approvals and such, however it does allow tagging a version..

Comment: As I understand the tags are applied to files, not to a specific version in the revision history.